# getting values from NSTextField in objective c and xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, nstextfield, quartz-composer

How can I continuously get data from an NSTextField and do this in the background? I'm doing this because I'm using a quartz composer plugin to get posted values in an NSTextField. This is within the same app.

Any ideas??

Elijah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "continuously", but the `controlTextDidChange:` delegate method will tell you when the text changes.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do like this:

theValue = (the text of the text field);

So I can then:

if (theValue > .001) {
(do something)
}

any ideas?

Comment: If you know that the field contains a number, you can do something like `[theField floatValue]`, since NSTextField is a subclass of NSControl.